# Trigger gif animation with accelerometer data using

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView) library to display a gif animation that I made in the if and else conditions of my main activity, but I'm having trouble using the library. I'm thinking it might be an Android Studio problem, but I keep getting can't resolve symbol gifImageView in this line of code (for the second gifImageView, now with stars)

```
    gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.*gifImageView*);
```

Here is the rest of my code

```java
package shake.shake;

/**
 * Created by ink on 3/24/16.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView;

public class main extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private GifImageView gifImageView;
    private float mLastX, mLastY, mLastZ, calories;
    private boolean mInitialized;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private final float NOISE = (float) 4.0;

    ;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.vertical);
        mInitialized = false;
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
// can be safely ignored for this demo
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        TextView tvC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calories);
        TextView tvX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
        TextView tvZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z_axis);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        if (!mInitialized) {
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            tvX.setText("0.0");
            tvC.setText("0.0");
            tvZ.setText("0.0");
            mInitialized = true;
        } else {
            float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
            float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);
            if (deltaX < NOISE) deltaX = (float) 0.0;
            if (deltaY < NOISE) deltaY = (float) 0.0;
            if (deltaZ < NOISE) deltaZ = (float) 0.0;
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            tvX.setText(Float.toString(deltaX));
            tvZ.setText(Float.toString(deltaZ));

                if (deltaX > deltaY) {
                    gifImageView.startAnimation();
                    ;
                    calories++;
                } else if (deltaY > deltaX) {
                    gifImageView.startAnimation();
                    calories++;
                } else {
                    gifImageView.stopAnimation();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Calories:"/>
    <TableLayout
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="X-Axis"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"

                android:text="Y-Axis"

                android:gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Z-Axis"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/x_axis"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/z_axis"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/calories"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/vertical"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please, what do you mean by "for the second gifImageView"? The first one runs ok?

Comment: sorry if that was unclear, android studio keeps telling me it cant resolve symbol for

    gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView); <---- that gifImageView

Comment: Oh... I see now. Thanks. You've already signed that with stars ;) Sorry for it. Now I was wondering... how is your xml configured to show this gifImageView? Because **findViewById** is not locating it.

Comment: ahh that may be it, I added to OP

Comment: You named the component on your XML as "vertical", but your java is searching for someone called "gifImageView".... Then correct you XML by using this `android:id="@+id/gifImageView"` instead of this `android:id="@+id/vertical"` or change `(GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);` to this `(GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.vertical);` on your java code. You have the choice :D

Comment: have it declared correctly now, still doesn't work. I think I have a problem in my java with displaying the image

Comment: If you allow me, start again, return to the GitHub from felipe, there you will find usage orientations, sample code etc. Read patiently, step by step, revising all, not forgetting anything. I'm sure you will get it.

Comment: going through now doing that, was hoping it was something small :)

Comment: Ahaha... keep it up man, U can do it! Sorry not helping much... in a rush too here... for days already :((( waw